# Reverse movement in Vim line auto-completion

Tags: vim

By default, line-completion in Vim starts at the last entry in the popup and pressing Ctrl-N twice loops around and then selects the first entry. This is in contrast to word-completion which starts at the first entry. I find the latter to be more intuitive. Is there any way to get line-completion to behave in a similar manner?

I don't know why it has been implemented in this manner. Though it is nothing more than tiny annoyance, it's like an itch which I've been yearning to scratch for years.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're annoyed at the inconsistency in where the cycle starts, but it is consistent with word completion started with Ctrl-p. Perhaps that's what Bram Moolenar prefers to think of as the default means of word completion?

Comment: Hmmm, that's a very good point. To accommodate this change in perspective, I'll rephrase my question as get word/line completion to start at first entry in the popup.

Comment: I recognize my answer isn't a solution. It's Vim, so it should be configurable, right?

Comment: I hope so. I tried the simplest solution I could think of viz. mapping <C-X><C-L> to <C-X><C-L><C-N><C-N> but for some reason the second <C-N> doesn't work.